# Switch from using one database to having one for auth and one for everything else

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models, django-migrations

Within my Django app I currently only have one DB, under settings it is default. What I want to do is port over all of the Auth tables created by Django to a separate database, Ill say SiteAuth for now.

I have copied all of the auth tables over to the SiteAuth db, but I am not sure how to integrate those changes within the site. I know I am going to have to add another db the databases section of settings, But I am not sure how to do the migrations, or how to specify which database I want to query.

How would I do the migrations? how would I specify which database I want to query? how would my models.py change?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a router. Check this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/

I would recommend to keep the auth in the default db, and move the other stuff in the new one. On the other questions the docs are very descriptive, but to summarize you need to add stuff to the Meta class of your models.